# tf.exe info /version:T does not get latest

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tf-cli, tfvc

I am using tf.exe to get the latest information of a path but

```
tf.exe info $/Path /version:T
```

only gives me the very first info. But I need the latest ones obviously. Using VS2013 and the build-in history I can see the latest.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're requesting the `info` for the root directory. Normally such folders are only created once and as such will only have **one** history element. When you look at the history list in Visual studio, you're looking at the recursive history (of the folder and all the subfolders and files under it).

`tf info` has a `/recursive` option, but it will list the latest version of each file in source control (which isn't very helpful).

I suspect that you're after something from the results that `tf info` returns, so if you could update your question to explain what you need, there might be another command that can help you.

If you're looking for the latest changeset number under a specific path, then `tf changeset /latest /noprompt` might work for you.